# How can I prove that $E[(Y-E[Y|X])^2]=E[Y^2]-E[(E[Y|X])^2]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $(X,Y)$ random vector $\Bbb R^2$-valuated, absolutely continous, with known density $f_{X,Y}$ (but I don't think we really need this) I have to exploit conditional expectation properties to prove that

$$
E[(Y-E[Y|X])^2]=E[Y^2]-E[(E[Y|X])^2]\;.
$$

Now developing the square, we get
$$
E[(Y-E[Y|X])^2]=E[Y^2]-2E[YE[Y|X]]+E[(E[Y|X])^2]
$$
hence I should prove that
$$
E[YE[Y|X]]=E[(E[Y|X])^2]
$$
but here is where I'm stuck. It must be ridicolously simple, it's obvious my eyes are missing something, but I can't understand what!

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that 
$$E[YE[Y|X]]=E[E[YE[Y|X]|X]]$$
by law of total expectation 
$$=E[E[Y|X]E[Y|X]]=E[(E[Y|X])^2]$$
by "taking out what is known" Since $E[Y|X]$ is function of $X$